# Can you specify which Cognito Callback URl to use in certain scenarios

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have secured my REST API with Cognito, however once authenticated I am trying to forward the user to an API endpoint. I know that you can specify multiple callback URLs in the hosted UI settings, but how can I be sure which one will be used? How do I specify? For example if I want to redirect the user to a get endpoint from the hosted UI the callback URL that should be used is a, whereas if I want them to get forwarded to a post endpoint the UI will use callback URL b